Формирование многовложенных URL-адресов Wordpress
Почему могут формироваться подобные URL-адреса на Wordpress:

{**site}/**brends/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/tekstil/dodo/

Как решить данную проблему?

Сами по себе не могут
